# Reiterating through a list of cells, in a specific column, to find when the list of values end

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of cells in a column that contains a value. The idea of the script is to go through a list of values ( string or long) and discover if the cell is empty or not. When it reaches an empty cell, it will stop counting and then msgbox the total number of cells containing a value, within that column.

I have given this ago, using the following code, and I constantly keep getting Excel not responded. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
    Sub Tester()


    Blockquote

Dim CellNumber As Long
Dim CellLetter As String
Dim Cell As String
Dim Total as Long
Dim cellEmpty As Boolean
Letter = "A"
Number = 1

Cell = CellLetter & CellNumber

Do
If Not IsEmpty(Range(Cell).Value) Then
CellNumber = CellNumber + 1
Total = Total + 1
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range(Cell).Value) Then
cellEmpty = True
End If
Loop While cellEmpty = False


End Sub
```

Comment: The reason Excel is crashing is because the cell with the address "Cell" is never empty.  You reset the "CellNumber" variable, but never set the address of "Cell" again after the first time.  If you add this line after resetting "CellNumber", it should work better.

    Cell = CellLetter & CellNumber

Comment: Why not use a formula?

Comment: If you have to do this in using VBA.. and you just want to get the count of rows.. why not just use: `Sheet1.Range("A1").end(xlUp).row`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, Counter As Long

    'Change Sheet name (Sheet1) if neede
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Counter = 0

        'Change starting point (1) if needed
        For i = 1 To Lastrow
            'Change Column (A) if needed
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
                MsgBox "The total number of non empty cells are " & Counter & "."
            Else
                Counter = Counter + 1
                    If i = Lastrow Then
                        MsgBox "The total number of non empty cells are " & Counter & "."
                    End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding. 
I have sorted it with the following:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim CellNumber As Integer
Dim CellLetter As String
Dim Cell As String
Dim Total As Long
Dim cellEmpty As Boolean
CellLetter = "A"
CellNumber = 1
Total = 0

Do
Cell = CellLetter & CellNumber
If Not IsEmpty(Range(Cell).Value) Then
CellNumber = CellNumber + 1

Total = Total + 1

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range(Cell).Value) Then
cellEmpty = True
End If
Loop While cellEmpty = False

MsgBox Total
End Sub
```